# JSF 2.0 : How to redirect to the protected page after using HttpServletRequest.login

Tags: java, authentication, jsf-2

I'm trying to use HttpServletRequest.login with form based authentication.

All is ok (the container tells if login/password are good), except that after the user has entered his login, I don't know how to redirect the user to the protected page he asked for (the login form is redisplayed). How to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

The code:

web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>security</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/loginwithlogin.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/noaut.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Page loginwithlogin.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Authentication</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            Login :
            <h:inputText value="#{login.login}" required="true" />
            <p/>
            Mot de passe :
            <h:inputSecret value="#{login.password}" required="true" />
            <p/>
            <h:commandButton value="Connexion" action="#{login.submit}">
                 <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:messages />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Update: without Ajax it does not work.

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Login implements Serializable {
  private String login;
  private String password;
  // getters and setters 
  ...

  public void submit() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = 
            (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {
        request.login(login, mdp);
        context.addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
                "OK", null));
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        context.addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                "Bad login", null));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of container managed form based authentication, the login page is under the covers opened by a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) and the original request URI is therefore available as a request attribute with the name as identified by [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI). Request attributes (basically, the request scope) is in JSF available by [`ExternalContext#getRequestMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29).

Thus, this should do:

```
private String requestedURI;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    requestedURI = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

    if (requestedURI == null) {
        requestedURI = "some/default/home.xhtml";
    }
}

public void submit() throws IOException {
    // ...

    try {
        request.login(username, password);
        externalContext.redirect(requestedURI);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        context.addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                "Bad login", null));
    }
}
```

You only need to make the bean `@ViewScoped` (JSF) or `@ConversationScoped` (CDI) instead of `@SessionScoped` (and absolutely not `@RequestScoped`; otherwise a different approach needs to be used with `<f:param>` and `<f:viewParam>`).

Comment: It works (with just a cast to String for requestedURI). Great! BalusC, I was waiting for your answer! I have read your articles for a long time and I have always found them very interesting and with a very big expertise. I tried to get this URI but I couldn't manage to get the good value. Your solution with an init method launched before the submit is very clever. Thank you very much for your help. Where did you get your information? By reading the sources?

Comment: Just a remark: the scope of the bean **mustn't** be session because it would redirect always to the same page (the first protected one that the user tried to access). I have used view scope (it's easier than conversation scope). In which case the requested URI could be null?

Comment: As to how I knew it, well, it's just how container managed authentication works as per Servlet API spec/standard. I'm next to JSF also very familiar with "plain" JSP/Servlet. And indeed, the session scope is insuitable, as answered. The forward request URI could be `null` if the enduser requested the login page itself directly.