# How to redirect to request page after basic athentication on websphere

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, websphere, basic-authentication

I'm trying to login the user using the `HttpServletRequest.login` method. I have setup my `web.xml`, created a `login.xhtml`, and mapped the action of the login button to my backing bean method called `performLogin`

The problem is to get the URL from where the user was redirected. Ie. he attempted to go to `index.xhtml`, but did not have a session, so is redirected to `login.xhtml`. I want to get the url he requested in the first place, so I try reading the `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI` from the request map as described by balusC here: [JSF 2.0 : How to redirect to the protected page after using HttpServletRequest.login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245749)

This does not work when using websphere, I guess because it does not forward, but redirect the user to the login page. However, since Websphere itself is able to do the correct forwarding when using the built in `j_security_check` action in the http-form, this must be possible to accomplish!

So, my question is basically; how can I get hold of this uri in order to forward the user to the correct page when logged in successfully, while running on websphere?

Comment: Sorry for not offering a solution to your question, but why do you use login and do the authentication yourself if the application server can do it for you declaratively? Use `web.xml` to define `security-constraint` and `login-config` with a `login` page and have the process managed by WAS. It saves you a lot of time.

Comment: I need to get the username and password that is typed in, because I use it as header parameters when communicating with a REST webservice which also has basic authentication. These will be deployed on different servers that use the same LDAP. If I let was handle it I am not able to get the password, only the username from the principal. So as long as the session is valid for the web application, it will be able to communicate with the rest service using the same credentials as he typed into the loginform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the url where you were redirected from on websphere, you can read the cookie named `WASReqURL`. The uri you get here includes hostname, port and context path, so I remove these in my method:

```
private String getRedirectUrl() {
    Map<String, Object> cookies = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();

    if (cookies.containsKey(WAS_REDIRECT_COOKIE_NAME)) {
        Cookie cookie = (Cookie) cookies.get(WAS_REDIRECT_COOKIE_NAME);

        String url = cookie.getValue();

        String context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();

        if (url != null && url.contains(context)) {
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf(context) + context.length() + 1);
        }

        return url;
    }
    return null;
}
```