# Form based login java web applications

Tags: security, jsf, authentication, jboss

I'm trying to perform a form-based login into a web application. I'm using JSF and JBoss v7.1.1. 
I've followed the instructions from the webpage 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncby

This is my login page:

Login to access secure pages:

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Username: " />
        <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" />

        <h:outputLabel value="Password: " />
        <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" />

        <h:outputText value="" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <br />
</form>
```

I have managed to perform the authentication but then, when the user is redirected to the restricted resource, I need to know the login data used by the user (e.g. username used to successfully perform the login). Does anyone know how to have access to this info? I would like to use it then in the ManagedBean class of the JSF pages.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `String userName = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote user is in JSF bean available by [`ExternalContext#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

```
String remoteUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
 // ...
```

This is under the covers obtained from [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29), which thus also means that it's available in JSF view as follows:

```
<p>You're logged in as #{request.remoteUser}.</p>
```

Or, more verbose:

```
<p>You're logged in as #{facesContext.externalContext.remoteUser}.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! It works! I've read that the programmatically form based authentication is much more flexible therefore I will try to do it. I will follow the Balus's indications from that link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245749/jsf-2-0-how-to-redirect-to-the-protected-page-after-using-httpservletrequest-l</h>.